# Can´t install tiny_tds in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, freetds, tiny-tds

When I run:

```
gem install tiny_tds
```

The output tells me that I need FreeTDS installed. Next, it shows me some configuration options and that I'll probably need an option. The options are the following:

```
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --with-freetds-dir
    --without-freetds-dir
    --with-freetds-include
    --without-freetds-include=${freetds-dir}/include
    --with-freetds-lib
    --without-freetds-lib=${freetds-dir}/lib
    --with-sybdb-dir
    --without-sybdb-dir
    --with-sybdb-include
    --without-sybdb-include=${sybdb-dir}/include
    --with-sybdb-lib
    --without-sybdb-lib=${sybdb-dir}/lib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
    --with-sybdblib
    --without-sybdblib
```

The problem is that none of the options work. Here´s an example of what happens:

```
C:\RailsApps>gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Using msys2 packages: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-freetds
Building native extensions with: '--with-freetds-dir'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5/ext/tiny_tds
    C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0 -r ./siteconf20220308-11104- 
    42q9r4.rb extconf.rb --with-freetds-dir
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --help
        --with-freetds-dir
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/mkmf.rb:1807:in `dir_config': undefined method `split' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)

      defaults = Array === dir ? dir : dir.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
                                          ^^^^^^
        from extconf.rb:56:in `<main>'
looking for freetds headers in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/include
 - /opt/local/include/freetds
 - /usr/local/include
 - /usr/local/include/freetds
looking for freetds library in the following directories:
 - /opt/local/lib
 - /opt/local/lib/freetds
 - /usr/local/lib
 - /usr/local/lib/freetds

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.1.0/tiny_tds-2.1.5/gem_make.out
```

I found an downloaded the FreeTDS binaries to try the Windows manual installation, but I don´t know where to place them or how to use them.

Comment: Just guessing here, based on the error message (`in dir_config`), perhaps `--with-freetds-dir` is supposed to take an argument. Yeah, I think that's it. See the [docs](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds#install) for an example.

Comment: Didn´t realize that. I added the path where I downloaded the FreeTDS binaries and completed the installation without problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to Jared Beck, I finally was able to precompile the FreeTDS binaries. I used Ruby on Rails in the past, but never needed to do such thing, so I didn´t know the syntax. I thought that running the command `gem install tiny_tds` included the FreeTDS installation. Then I noticed the configuration options and tried running `gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir`, but didn´t know that the command required the directory as an argument.

Finally, I downloaded the FreeTDS Windows binary from https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/, extracted it in C:, and ran the following command:

```
gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir=C:\freetds-1.00
```

Comment: Matías Leandro wrote: `gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-dir=C:\freetds-1.00` This works fine for me. The gem was installed. Is the folder `C:\freetds-1.00` necessary after installing the gem or is it only needed during the build process? Are there any *.exe files created? I'am asking, because in the `ruby/gem/folder/tiny_tds` I cannot find any?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out thanks to the previous posts, by looking at the freetds windows zipfile and the installed pacman package.

It's probably looking for the include folder headers at C:\Ruby31-x64\msys64\ucrt64\include
However it is at C:\Ruby31-x64\msys64\ucrt64\include\freetds
The .exe files interestingly are at C:\Ruby31-x64\msys64\ucrt64\bin and are found.

```
 gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=C:\Ruby31-x64\msys64\ucrt64\include\freetds
```

also see: [Tiny TDS GitHub Issue 503](https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/503)